# How would I go about creating a custom container view in Android?

Tags: java, android

I would like to create a view with a listener that acts sort of like a container or grocery bag. Any image or text that is dragged into it, gets collected and saved into a local database. Or rather the image name or string gets saved. I've created custom views before that displayed a custom row of data but I'm not sure how to create a "grocery bag" type of view. I've searched Google for creating a custom container view with listener but couldn't find anything related to what I am looking for. I'm not asking anyone to do it for me, just give me some advice or push in the right direction.

**Edit**
Just to clarify a little more. I already know how to drag and drop a view. The problem with that is that you can drop anywhere. What I want is a view that when something is dropped within its bounds, it gets the views' string or tag. Regardless of what kind of view that may be. Somehow this custom view has to know what kind of view was dropped within its bounds and remove that view on drop.

Comment: _Trying to understand your requirement as_

Divide the screen in 2 parts: (LHS & RHS)
LHS has some items (Like eggs, cake etc...)
RHS has a BAG (i.e. shopping bag)

When you drag & drop eggs from LHS to RHS (i.e. LHS to shopping bag) the item is added to the bill (i.e. Local DB)

Correct ??

Comment: You are covering what API levels ?
i.e. what is your expectation for MinSDKLevel ?

Comment: Looks like you want to read this and come here again with your problem doing it: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

Comment: @Pawan API 15+ what I envision is a custom class that knows when something has been dragged into it. Kind of like how 3d models have a collider in 3d games.

Comment: @Nanoc I'm familiar with drag and drop, what I'm hoping to achieve is a custom view class that has a "collider/trigger" type border

Comment: Yea, that android doc tells you how to make it

Comment: @SteveC. **Just a Suggestion**
Use CardView & try to check the application : "Trello"

In this application, you will get an idea to drag & drop Cards easily.

Comment: @SteveC. Also with every card you will have to set the TAG i.e. cardView.setTAG(UNIQUE_ID), once you drop the Card on the Basket you will get the TAG (i.e. cardView.getTAG) & you will insert that particular data in the DB.

Comment: @Pawan Thank you. Please see my edit. I know how to create drag and droppable views, I need to create a view that listens for anything entering its bounds through dragging and dropping. Thus removing the view being dragged and simultaneously inserting that views' TAG or String into a local database to be uploaded to a server later.

Comment: Like Nanoc already said...the documentation on drag&drop is pretty good. As far as i can tell your use case isn't special in any direction (or you should draw a picture?) 
Have a look at the part about intermediate events: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html#HandleDuring
The important thing to keep in mind is this: you **don't** drag and drop views back and forth. You move the metadata and handle this. So you need a model for your entries and a bit of business logic.

Answer (score 1):

```
   <view class="at.calista.quatscha.views.SwipebarLayout"
        android:id="@+id/sbl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <!-- Top View -->
        <Button android:text="Top" android:id="@+id/Button01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>

        <!-- Bottom View -->
        <Button android:text="Bottom" android:id="@+id/Button02" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. This example is for a swipeable layout that resembles a toolbar or tab layout. It doesn't give an example of a "container" type of view. Thank you though.

Answer (score 1):

You would need a method that determines whether two views overlap. For example, something like these methods could work for when the target view and the dragged item view are 2 distinct views in the same container view:

```
private Rect getScreenBounds(View view)
{
    int[] location = new int[2];
    view.getLocationOnScreen(location);

    return new Rect(location[0], location[1], location[0] + view.getWidth(), location[1] + view.getHeight());
}

private boolean doViewsIntersect(View dropTarget, View item)
{
    Rect dropRect = getScreenBounds(dropTarget);
    Rect itemRect = getScreenBounds(item);

    return Rect.intersects(dropRect, itemRect);
}
```

However, if the views being dragged are child views on a container, and that container has a special hit area where you want to perform the drop logic, then you can just use that hit area's `Rect` for the intersect test.

To save information on the `View`, you have a few options:

- You can use `view.setTag(key, object)` and `view.getTag(key)` to store whatever information you'd like on each item.
- If you are using a custom class for the items, you can just add a method to get the data from the view class.
- If you are using multiple different classes for the items, you could make an interface, and implement that interface on each draggable view class.

On an item's release, you could then check whether the areas/views intersect, and if they do, get whatever information you need from the dragged item to process as necessary, either using `getTag` or the method added to the view.

For example, this could be triggered via an `onTouchListener`, when you receive a `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` event. Here's an example of a listener that you can add on each item:

```
item.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
            if (doViewsIntesect(dropTarget, v))
            {
                Object data = v.getTag(DATA_KEY);
                //process data
                ((ViewGroup) v.getParent()).removeView(v); // to remove the item afterwards
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```